# Using jquery, how can I get this "inner text" of a li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have the following html and I am trying to figure out the right selector logic to read in certain part. **NOTE**: I can't change the html as this is being generated by a plugin.

```
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="">
      <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    MS Office
 </li>
 <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="">
      <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    Photoshop
 </li>
```

and I am trying to read out the text inside the

```
 <li class="select2-selection__choice">
```

but NOT including the

```
 <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove">
```

so for the example above, I am looking to parse out the following text:

```
 MS Office, Photoshop
```

Comment: @WhiteHat - I don't have a choice as this html is being generated by a plugin so this is what i am given (thus the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('.select2-selection__choice').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    console.log(text.trim());
});
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.select2-selection__choice').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    console.log(text.trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="">
      <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    MS Office
 </li>
 <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="">
      <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
    Photoshop
 </li>
```

Comment: this solution seems to include the "x" that is in the select2-selection__choice__remove span. which i don't want to include

Comment: check the console not the html ..

Comment: Please provide an explanation, not just code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.class` selector:

```
$('.select2-selection__choice').each(function() {
    var inneText = $(this).children().text();        
});
```